# Does javac ever generate static bridge methods?

Tags: java, jvm, decompiling

Bridge methods are used in java to handle covariance in derived methods, and to change visibility on derived methods.

However, both of these cases are for **instance** methods (as you can't derive static methods).

I was looking at how Kotlin generates argument defaults, and I was struck that it uses **static** bridge methods.

*I can't think of a circumstance under which Javac generates **static** bridge methods - can anyone else?*  (by this, I mean a method which has the ACC_BRIDGE flag (0x40) set, not just a semantically bridging method)

(fwiw - example code and decompilations (using cfr 0_124 with --hidebridgemethods false))

**Variance**

```
public class BridgeTest1Base<T> {
 public T frob() {
    return null;
 }
}

public class BridgeTest1Derived extends BridgeTest1Base<Integer> {
 public Integer frob() {
    return null;
 }
}
```

decompiles to

```
public class BridgeTest1Derived extends BridgeTest1Base<Integer> {
 @Override
 public Integer frob() {
    return null;
 }

 @Override
 public /* bridge */ /* synthetic */ Object frob() {
    return this.frob();
 }
}
```

**Visibility**

```
class BridgeTest2Base {
    public void frob() {
    }
}

public class BridgeTest2Derived extends BridgeTest2Base {}
```

decompiles to

```
public class BridgeTest2Derived extends BridgeTest2Base {
 @Override
 public /* bridge */ /* synthetic */ void frob() {
    super.frob();
 }
}
```

**Kotlin defaults - yum!**

```
class frob2() {

fun fred2(x: Int = 300, y: frob2 = mkFrob2(x)) {
    println("{this}{x}{y}")
}

fun mkFrob2(x: Int): frob2 {
    return this;
}

fun foobar() {
    fred2();
    fred2(100);
    fred2(100, frob2());
}
}
```

decompiles (into java) to (note the static bridge)

```
public final class frob2 {
public final void fred2(int x, @NotNull frob2 y) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull((Object)y, (String)"y");
    String string = "{this}{x}{y}";
    System.out.println((Object)string);
}

public static /* bridge */ /* synthetic */ void fred2$default(frob2 frob22, int n, frob2 frob23, int n2, Object object) {
    if ((n2 & 1) != 0) {
        n = 300;
    }
    if ((n2 & 2) != 0) {
        frob23 = frob22.mkFrob2(n);
    }
    frob22.fred2(n, frob23);
}

@NotNull
public final frob2 mkFrob2(int x) {
    return this;
}

public final void foobar() {
    frob2.fred2$default(this, 0, null, 3, null);
    frob2.fred2$default(this, 100, null, 2, null);
    this.fred2(100, new frob2());
}
}
```

Comment: I don't remember any circumstance under which javac would generate a static bridge method, but if I recall correctly, JDO post-processors do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bridge methods according to the Java Language Specification, which are the methods that should be annotated with `ACC_BRIDGE`, are there to ensure an *override compatible signature*, so that code invoking the method using the original signature will end up at the overridden method even if it has a different method signature at the bytecode level. The only applications in the Java programming language are type erasure and covariant return types.

Since `static` methods can not be overridden in that way that a caller could get redirected, there is no scenario in which a bridge method in the sense of the Java Language Specification can occur for a `static` method. Therefore, `javac` never produces a method that has `ACC_BRIDGE` and `ACC_STATIC` set.

It’s also a very questionable behavior to mark methods as bridge method on behalf of another language’s semantics. As [the JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6-200-A.7) says:

> The `ACC_BRIDGE` flag is used to indicate a bridge method generated by a compiler for the Java programming language.

There are other synthetic delegate methods that might be `static`, like nested class accessors or adapters for method references (e.g. for *varargs* or intersection types). These do not count as bridge methods.

Comment: This, I guess is the interesting bit - where do you find the definition of a bridge method to be 'override compatible'?  The JVMS (as you quote) defines one self referentially (i.e. not at all, other than to say ACC_BRIDGE).  The JLS only mentions it in passing in 15.12.4.5, again as a use, not as a definition.

Comment: Well yes, it’s hard to draw something from the specification, as to the JLS, it’s an implementation detail, and to the JVMS, it has no relevant semantic. The best indicator is the history, as neither the term “bridge method” nor the `ACC_BRIDGE` flag did not exist prior to Java 5 and they were precisely introduced for binary compatibility when dealing with generics and covariant return types. See [the tutorial on bridge methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html)…

Comment: Archaeology, I like it!  Yup, that oracle doc clearly states the bridges are to handle erasure wrt inheritance issues (though alas no mention of visibility).  Sold ;)  Why the creators of kotlin chose to use it for filling in defaults, that's for another day!

Comment: @lab27: indeed, I found no mentioning of these “visibility bridge methods” somewhere and the code perfectly runs without, as it did before Java 5. I don’t know, in which version `javac` started to generate these bridge methods for `public` methods inherited from non-`public` classes. As long as a compiler correctly uses the compile-time receiver type for method invocations, they are not needed at all. Perhaps, it’s a Reflection issue.

Comment: @Holger I think [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6342411) is when bridge methods started to be generated

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK `javac` will not generate bridge methods as *static* at the moment, this does not mean that in future there will no case for the bridge methods to be static (I am not aware of even a hypothetical example though).

Bridge methods are used in two cases : when you are dealing with generics as you have shown it and covariant return types when overriding.

In the first case, bridge methods are created when you implement a generic interface or extend a generic class.

For interfaces, when you override a generic method (which has to be non-static), there will be a bridge method created, but since it will delegate to the *non-static* one, it is itself non-static. Well, java-8, allows static method inside interfaces, but, being static, these are non-overridable (they are not even inherited, as opposed to static methods from classes).

For generic classes, same story stands. Only *instance* methods are overridable, and even if such a bridge method is created, since it will call a non-static method, it will itself be such. The small caveat is that static methods from classes are inherited, but they are not overridable (as opposed to interface ones), thus no bridge methods.

The last example is covariant return types:

```
static class Parent {

}

static class Child extends Parent {

}

static class First {
    public Parent go() {
        return new Parent();
    }
}

static class SubFirst extends First {
    @Override
    public Child go() {
        return new Child();
    }
}
```

Here a bridge method will be created in `SubFirst`, but since you can only override instance methods (how many times have I said this already?), there is no need for the bridge method to be itself static.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, javac generates static bridge methods to allow inner classes to access private outer class methods.

Take for example this source:

```
package bridge;

public class C {
    private void doIt() {
    }

    class D {
        {
            doIt();
        }
    }
}
```

Javap shows you the static `access$0` method that was generated:

```
$ javap -p -cp target/classes bridge.C
Compiled from "C.java"
public class bridge.C {
  public bridge.C();
  private void doIt();
  static void access$0(bridge.C);
}
```

It's content:

```
  static void access$0(bridge.C);
    descriptor: (Lbridge/C;)V
    flags: ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #17                 // Method doIt:()V
         4: return
```

Comment: This is a bridging method, but it's not annotated in the class file as a bridge method - it doesn't have the ACC_BRIDGE (0x40) flag set on the method.  (if you use javap on my examples, you will see ACC_BRIDGE).  I appreciate that my question wasn't specific with regards to that, I will update it!

Comment: Why is the ACC_BRIDGE method so important to you? This type of bridge method is almost identical to the Kotlin bridge method that you showed. It's probably because inner classes predate the ACC_BRIDGE flag that it isn't set on these outer class accessor bridge methods.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt may be because these are not bridge methods? they are synthetic, but not bridge

Comment: The ACC_BRIDGE is important to me because my pet project is a decompiler ;)  ( CFR ).  For java, it is almost always safe to hide ACC_BRIDGE, but for Kotlin-as-Java, that is not the case.   A simple heuristic seems to be that static bridges should not be hidden.  Hence this question!

Comment: @Eugene Define "bridge methods". And don't say "Whatever Javac labels as ACC_BRIDGE" - that means that no other compiler should be allowed to emit that flag. Bridge methods, by most definitions, are methods that bridge a call to another method. And the static method generated to access private outer class methods is definitely an example of those. The Kotlin method to simulate default arguments: much less so.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I do agree with you, of course. But this is not what the OP was after

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt and btw `Method#isBridge` will return false for your example IIRC

Answer (score 0):

> See [the tutorial on bridge methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html)…
> @Holger
> [comment 83410934_48213426](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202814/does-javac-ever-generate-static-bridge-methods/76346429#comment83410934_48213426)

I simplified this document and tried it.

```java
public class Main {
    public static abstract class Node<T> {
        public abstract void setData(T data);
    }

    public static class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {
        private Integer data;

        @Override
        public void setData(Integer data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Run `javac Main.java`, and `javap -v 'Main$MyNode'`.
As a result, found `ACC_BRIDGE!`

```
public void setData(java.lang.Object);
  descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  flags: (0x1041) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC
  Code:
    stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
        0: aload_0
        1: aload_1
        2: checkcast     #13                 // class java/lang/Integer
        5: invokevirtual #15                 // Method setData:(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
        8: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 6: 0

public void setData(java.lang.Integer);
  descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
  flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
        0: aload_0
        1: aload_1
        2: putfield      #7                  // Field data:Ljava/lang/Integer;
        5: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 11: 0
      line 12: 5
```